# PA├ ∃xP(x) but PA$\nvdash$ P(n) for any n?

Tags: first-order-logic, incompleteness, nonstandard-models

Problem :
**Let P(x) be a wff with one free variable x in the language of PA and $PA\vdash \exists P(x)$. And let PA be $\omega$-consistent.**

**Then, is there a natural number $n$ s.t. $PA\vdash P(n)$?**

---

Since PA is $\omega$-consistent and the standarad arithmetic model $\mathbb{N} $ is a model of PA,

There should be a natural number $n$ s.t. $\mathbb{N} \models P(n)$. Also, $PA \vDash \exists xP(x)$.

Since PA isn't complete, it may happen that although P(n) is true on $\mathbb{N}, PA \nvdash P(n)$.

Also, the condition that P(n) is a sentence is required since
if P(x) had free variables other than x, then it may fail since
$PA\vdash (\exists x) x=y$, but for any $n\in \mathbb{N}, PA\nvdash n=y$.

One of tries was that finding a property P(x) s.t. there is a sequence of non-standard models $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ where $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, A_n\nvDash P(n)$, but $ A_n\vDash \exists xP(x).$  (Well, such P(x) also should be expressible in the language of PA though.)

And for a similar problem but ∀ is used instead of ∃, (i.e. finding G(x) where $PA\nvdash \forall x G(x) $ but $PA\vdash G(n)$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$), this is solved since there is Goodstein's Theorem. With a combibation of $\neg$, it may be a key.

Or using Diagonalization lemma may help, but still I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $P(x)$ be the formula $$"\!\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf PA)\vee x\textrm { is the Gödel number of a proof of a contradiction from }\mathsf{PA}.\!"$$

Clearly, $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\exists x P(x).$

But suppose, with the aim of reaching a contradiction, that there is a natural number $n$ such that $\mathsf{PA}\vdash P(\pmb{n}).$ Writing out what this means, $\mathsf{PA}$ proves the sentence

$$"\!\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf PA)\vee \pmb{n}\textrm { is the Gödel number of a proof of a contradiction from }\mathsf{PA}.\!"$$

We've assumed that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, so $n$ is not actually the Gödel number of a proof of a contradiction from $\mathsf{PA}.$

Being the Gödel number of the proof of a contradiction from $\mathsf{PA}$ is a finitistic property, so we can examine the specific number $n$ and conclude that the sentence $$"\!\pmb{n}\textrm{ is not the Gödel number of a proof of a contradiction from }\mathsf{PA}\!"$$ is provable in $\mathsf{PA}.$

It follows that $\mathsf{PA}\vdash \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA}),$ contradicting Gödel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: +1. Note to the OP that in a precise sense this example is optimal: it is $\Pi^0_1$, and no $\Sigma^0_1$ example can exist since $\mathsf{PA}$ is $\Sigma^0_1$-complete.

Comment: @mohottnad Yes, $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ must be assumed since otherwise everything is provable in $\mathsf{PA}$ (in particular, all the sentences $P(\pmb{n})$ would be provable). Given that consistency assumption, no $P(\pmb{n})$ is provable in $\mathsf{PA}$ even though $\exists x P(x)$ is.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, yes now I've seen OP already let PA be ω-consistent in the first paragraph.

Comment: @mohottnad Yes, but that’s stronger than is needed. Just consistency is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your optimal answer!   Here is a similar but may be a more general idea.   For any undecidable sentence G of PA, let $G'(x)$ be $((G \wedge x=0) \vee (\neg G \wedge \neg x=0))$.  $PA \vdash ∃xG'(x)$ since $PA \vdash (G \vee \neg G)$ and $PA \vdash (G'(0) \vee G'(1))$. But if $PAㅏG'(n)$ for some natural number n, then $(n=0 →PA\vdash G)$  and $(n≠0 → PA\vdash ~G)$. Contradicts.